# How to create a duplicate of existing User model - django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

How to create a duplicate of the existing User model which display objects only if a condition is satisfied?

**Here in this pic, pending users should show all the users with is_active = True:**

[image]

In the documentation, there was a similar statement:

`pendinguser = models.ForeignKey(User, limit_choices_to={'is_staff': True})`

How and where to add this to make this work?

Comment: you can use proxy model, you can define your own comparison in it without affecting the User model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example:
you have your user model 'User'

Now create a new model and inherit User model like this

```
class ProxyUser(User):
     objects = ProxyUserManagaer()
     class Meta:
          proxy = True
```

Now create you custom definition of this Proxy model in manager function:

```
class ProxyUserManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(FeatureManager, self).get_queryset().filter(<add your custom definiton her>)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will implement it now. But can you brief about the Manager class? And why it is suited here?

Comment: Thank you, and I was able to do it using a proxy model like you suggested and also with the help of [this article](http://mahner.org/separating-staff-and-user-accounts-in-djangos-admin)